# My EDTA titration isn't giving the right titre

Tags: analytical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, titration

I am, as a fun off-syllabus investigation, looking at hard water and how effective the EDTA titration method is, for permanent and temporary hard water.
I ran a titration today and had horrific results. I actually knew the concentration of my water sample: $\pu{0.005 M}$ made up with $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}.$ My EDTA was $\pu{0.01 M}.$

I'm clearly looking at a $1:1$ ratio between $\ce{Ca^2+}$ ions and EDTA molecules. I had $\pu{50 cm^3}$ in my conical flask, so at this concentration, I'd expect my titre to be about $\pu{25 cm^3}.$ I added a little Eriochrome Black T, 8 drops of $\mathrm{pH}~10$ buffer, and my colour change was more or less instant.

If I'd actually bothered to work out that I should aim for a $\pu{25 cm^3}$ titre, I wouldn't have wasted my time but instead, I diluted my EDTA to $\pu{0.001 M},$ and my next few titres were $\pu{4.8 cm^3}.$

Now, I know very little about the buffer. Am I putting far too little in? Or is my EDTA actually, $\pu{0.5 M}$ instead of $\pu{0.01}?$

Comment: We cannot predict what went wrong until and unless you add exact details. How much mass did you weigh out? How was the calcium standard made? Calcium nitrate is not a primary standard. What were your calculations? Did you use di-sodium EDTA or EDTA? If you add those details, I will tell you how to make a calcium standard.

Comment: 8 buffer drops is suspicious. Buffers are not added in drops, but in substantial relative volume. Combining 8 drops with 25 mL 0.01 M EDTA is like combining it formally with about 8 drops of 1 M EDTA, so resulting pH woild be very different to expected pH=10.

Comment: 0.05 M Na2H2-EDTA is about the top practical concentration, regarding solubility. Solubility of H4-EDTA is significantly less than of the disodium salt.